Java Eclipse: JFrame deadlock while running the following code inside my Maven project on a Mac
I tried to run the following code on Eclipse with my Maven project:
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            System.out.println("Starting ...");
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
            System.out.println("JFrame created");
            frame.setTitle("JFrameCenter Position");
            frame.add(new JLabel("Some content to write", SwingConstants.CENTER));
            frame.setSize(400, 300);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("JFrame now visible");
        });
    }
}

With eclipse and Maven I get a dead lock when creating a new Frame object. It just does not work. No error message on the console, just deadlock. In debug mode it shows the EDT as running but nothing is visible.
Eclipse version is:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0)
Build id: 20231201-2043
Maven version is 3.9.6
Operating system: macOS Sonoma 14.4.1
Java:  OpenJDK 17.0.10 (could repeat with different ones)
I tried to run the code with Eclipse.
The result printout on the console is the following:
"Starting ..."
Nothing else happens. No window is coming up.
This means that the program somehow sticks at the creation of the Frame object. Apparently the VM is working and showing up that the EDT is also active but there is no reaction on the console despite the "Starting ..." line
I also tried alternatives:
NetBeans Maven     --> worked
Eclipse ANT        --> worked
Has someone come across the same behavior or can anyone help me out here please?
Thank you very much and best regards...
Harry
